# Integrate SQLMX in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sqlmx

I wanted to open in IntelliJ a NonStop/SQLMX database using the driver com.tandem.t4jdbc.

After the configuration the connection is successful, I can also open the table with the double click, but it looks like the column are not immediately recognized and the label is loaded instead of the name in the column header.

When I connect I have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.tandem.t4jdbc.SQLMXResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel(SQLMXResultSetMetaData.java:145)
  at com.intellij.database.remote.jdbc.impl.RemoteResultSetMetaDataImpl.getColumnLabel(RemoteResultSetMetaDataImpl.java:69)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
  at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
  at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
  at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
  at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.getColumnLabel(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor351.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.invokeRemote(RemoteUtil.java:179)
  at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil.access$300(RemoteUtil.java:39)
  at com.intellij.execution.rmi.RemoteUtil$RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteUtil.java:275)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy200.getColumnLabel(Unknown Source)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.MetaDataUtil$ResultSetWrapper.<init>(MetaDataUtil.java:86)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.MetaDataUtil$RemoteResultSetWrapper.<init>(MetaDataUtil.java:224)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.MetaDataUtil$ResultSetWrapper.wrap(MetaDataUtil.java:96)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.ClosableIt$ResultSetDelegateIt.<init>(ClosableIt.java:253)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.ClosableIt$ResultSetClosableIt.<init>(ClosableIt.java:184)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.UserDefinedTypeIt.<init>(UserDefinedTypeIt.java:17)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.jdbcMetadataWrappers.DatabaseMetaDataWrapper.userDefinedTypes(DatabaseMetaDataWrapper.java:649)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.introspectTypesInSchema(GenericIntrospector.java:451)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.lambda$introspectSchemasByCatalogs$7(GenericIntrospector.java:214)
  at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.lambda$forEachSchemaInCatalog$15(GenericIntrospector.java:249)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.forEachCatalog(GenericIntrospector.java:244)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.forEachSchemaInCatalog(GenericIntrospector.java:249)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.introspectSchemasByCatalogs(GenericIntrospector.java:211)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.introspectSchemas(GenericIntrospector.java:200)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.lambda$null$0(GenericIntrospector.java:157)
  at org.jetbrains.dekaf.core.BaseFacade.inSession(BaseFacade.java:125)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.lambda$introspectAuto$1(GenericIntrospector.java:151)
  at com.intellij.database.model.impl.BaseModel.modify(BaseModel.java:114)
  at com.intellij.database.model.impl.BaseModel.modify(BaseModel.java:99)
  at com.intellij.database.model.impl.BaseModel.modify(BaseModel.java:84)
  at com.intellij.database.introspection.GenericIntrospector.introspectAuto(GenericIntrospector.java:151)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.introspectDatabases(DatabaseModelLoader.java:419)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.lambda$null$2(DatabaseModelLoader.java:312)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.withFacade(DatabaseModelLoader.java:533)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.lambda$introspect$3(DatabaseModelLoader.java:295)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager.lambda$null$0(DataSourceSyncManager.java:40)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionManager$Executor.perform(DatabaseConnectionManager.java:363)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionManager$Executor.lambda$sync$2(DatabaseConnectionManager.java:302)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.withAsyncFriendly(AsyncUtil.java:158)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionManager$Executor.sync(DatabaseConnectionManager.java:298)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseConnectionManager$Builder.sync(DatabaseConnectionManager.java:112)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager.lambda$static$1(DataSourceSyncManager.java:39)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager$SyncProcessor$1.perform(DataSourceSyncManager.java:242)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.introspect(DatabaseModelLoader.java:292)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.lambda$run$0(DatabaseModelLoader.java:272)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.LocalDataSource.performBatch(LocalDataSource.java:1184)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DatabaseModelLoader$IntrospectionSession.run(DatabaseModelLoader.java:270)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.DataSourceSyncManager$SyncProcessor.performSync(DataSourceSyncManager.java:244)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$null$6(AsyncUtil.java:55)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$underProgress$14(AsyncUtil.java:127)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.underProgress(AsyncUtil.java:133)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.underProgress(AsyncUtil.java:127)
  at com.intellij.database.dataSource.AsyncUtil.lambda$captureIndicator$7(AsyncUtil.java:55)
  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
  at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) (no stack trace).
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Looks like issue with jdbc driver. Can you try with different jdbc driver version?

Comment: I was trying to search for other drivers but I couldn't find any on the internet. Then it's strange because in SQuirreL software this driver is working and I can see properly the column name.
Do you know where could I find a different version of this driver?

Comment: I have the same behaviour with all the databases configured with that driver, so probably the problem is really the driver itself, but still it's strange than on SQuirreL it works properly.

Comment: Hello HP & NONSTOP,  I believe your jdbc drivers have scope for improvement. Please do something - NONSTOP is STOPPING progress :). I have the same problem with t4sqlmx-3.3.jar

Comment: Same issue here with the 3.5 driver. Do not know what kind of magic SQuirreL is doing for it to work there. Anyone got any updates on this? Would love to use another tool besides SQuirreL...